# Count all inputs sum

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to calculate the total sum of all inputs. 
Before the calculation all the inputs are hidden. Let's suppose, there 30 inputs, and they are randomly revealed by the visitors.

The only thing I've managed to do is to identify revealed inputs, without class".hidden". But when "count total" is clicked its input should display the sum of only revealed inputs.val()

I believe, it should be done with loops, but have no idea.

Help me, please, to achieve this!

```js
let productsObj = $('.order__row');

$('.count__total').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    for (let i = 0; i < productsObj.length; i++) {
      const element = productsObj[i];
      if (!$(element).hasClass('hidden')) {
// calculate the total sum
      } else {
      
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" order__row order__row-fish hidden">
  <div class="order__wrapper">            
    <input class="order__title" type="text" value="Fish" readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="order__wrapper">            
    <input class="order__price" type="number" value="500" readonly>
  </div>  
  <div class="order__wrapper">            
    <input class="order__qnt" type="number" value="1" >
  </div>
</div>

<div class=" order__row order__row-meat hidden">
  <div class="order__wrapper">            
    <input class="order__title" type="text" value="meat" readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="order__wrapper">            
    <input class="order__price" type="number" value="500" readonly>
  </div>  
  <div class="order__wrapper">            
    <input class="order__qnt" type="number" value="1" >
  </div>
</div>

<a class="count__total" href="#">Count total</a>
                  <input class="total__price" type="text" name="Total" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when "count total" is clicked its input should display the sum of
>   only revealed inputs.val()

Directly fetch the non-`hidden` inputs only

```
$('.count__total').each('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var total = 0;
    $('.order__row:not(.hidden)').each( function(){
      total += +$(this).find( ".order__qnt" ).val(); //use .order__price if price has to be total'ed
    });
    console.log( total );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work as looping through the inputs and sum its valkue:

```
let productsObj = $('.order__row');

$('.count__total').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < productsObj.length; i++) {
      const element = productsObj[i];
      if (!$(element).hasClass('hidden')) {
        sum += $(element).find('.order__qnt').val();
// calculate the total sum
      } else {
          // return false;
      }
    }
  });
```